# How to do parellel arrays with following information

Tags: javascript, arrays

For this question, it might be a little vague, because i just dont understand it at all, its probably the wording.. from what i learn in class it seems a lot harder. So im lost as to where to begin.. if someone can help walk me through it easier i would appreciate it!

**Question:** Design a Program that will read the same parts inventory file described in the problem 6. the parts are: (Record code, part number, part description, and inventory balance) validate the record code and part number on each record, and print the details of all valid records whose part numbers fall within the value AA3000 and AA3999 inclusive. Also print a count of these selected records at the end of the parts listing.

Now, i hope you can understand what its asking because i sure dont. Any help or a small walk through would be awesome. This is the code i am supposed to start out from that was given to me.

```
var Rec_Code = new Array(11,11,11,12,11,12,11,13,11,14);
var Numer    = new Array(2000,3000,3003,3008,3999,2000,1090,3678,3777,3543);
var Alpha    = new Array("AA","AA","AX","AA","AA","AA","AB","AA","AN","AA");
var Desc     = new Array("X","L","S","F","R","U","T","N","Q","Y");
var Inv_Bal  = new Array(12,13,14,23,34,56,32,45,67,77);
```

also, this was given to me, which is basically what i have to do, but dont know how to completely do it.

- use the vars that I provided to create 5 parallel arrays, RecCode, AlphaPart of part number, Numeric part of the part number,Description and Inventory. You need to search the first 3 arrays for:

  1. RecCode of 11
  2. AlphaCode of 'AA':
  3. Numeric Code betweewn 3000 - 3999 inclusive

when you find a match increment a count and display the Description and Inventory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all arrays are the same length and sorted appropriately, you can loop over one and display the information you need:

```
var count = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < Rec_Code.length; i++)
{
    if(Rec_Code[i] == 11 && Alpha[i] == 'AA' && (Numer[i] >= 3000 && Numer[i] <= 3999))
    {
        console.log(Desc[i]);
        console.log(Inv_Bal[i]);    
        count++;    
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh okay that makes sense, i attempted to do that but its more complex then what we learn in class. so, that finds the values i need, but now i need to display the var Desc, and Inv_Bal. They are already sorted, so how would i make it print out the correct ones?

Comment: The `console.log` calls print out the correct values from Desc and Inv_Bal using the current index in the for loop. It's really up to you how you print these values out. I didn't have a specification on how to do this so I just used `console.log`.

Comment: awesome, just next time you help. it would be better to take me through step by step rather then just doing it for me. Thanks a lot tho works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Rec_Code = new Array(11,11,11,12,11,12,11,13,11,14);
var Numer    = new Array(2000,3000,3003,3008,3999,2000,1090,3678,3777,3543);
var Alpha    = new Array("AA","AA","AX","AA","AA","AA","AB","AA","AN","AA");
var Desc     = new Array("X","L","S","F","R","U","T","N","Q","Y");
var Inv_Bal  = new Array(12,13,14,23,34,56,32,45,67,77);

var count = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < Rec_Code.length; i++)
{
    if(Rec_Code[i] == 11 && Alpha[i] == 'AA' && (Numer[i] >= 3000 && Numer[i] <= 3999))
    {
        console.log(Desc[i]);
        console.log(Inv_Bal[i]);    
        count++;    
    }
}
```